# This specific CSS property is not applied (crossed out in inspection mode)

Tags: html, css, nav

I am making a simple website as a newbie using bootstrap 5. While making a navigation bar and personally customizing it, I noticed that one of the CSS property wasn't applying at all. Specifically, my font size on my logo does not change despite the constant changing and fixing.

I feel like this is definitely an easy solution but I just don't get it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand" href="#">HELP ME OUT</h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active navtag" aria-current="page" href="dashmain.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Guide</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #408EC6;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-left: 4px solid black;
    user-select: none;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    animation: color-change 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0% {
        color: #1E2761;
    }

    15% {
        color: #7A2048;
    }

    25% {
        color: wheat;
    }

    50% {
        color: #1E2761;
    }

    75% {
        color: #7A2048;
    }

    80% {
        color: wheat;
    }

    100% {
        color: #1E2761;
    }
}
```

I already did some tinkering like using the right metric and even changing the html tag. It was working before I remember. However, right after I finished applying a hover animation for the text, it just didn't change to my preferred size.

Comment: Bootstrap itself probably already sets a font-size for `.navbar-brand`. You need to include your own stylesheet _after_ the BS stylesheet, if you want your own rules that have the same [Specificity)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as the ones BS is using, to take precedence.

Comment: @CBroe I get what you mean but as I said in the last paragraph, it changed before so maybe it had some bug?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, can only guess that you are misinterpreting something else about the situation, or that the change you made wasn't actually just what you say it was. Fact is, Bootstrap _does_ apply the color with a rule with the exact same selector (Instead the navbar text in the example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#text, and the CSS inspector will show you) - and if you embed your stylesheet with the _same_ selector before that, then the BS rule will simply "win."

Comment: And "crossed out in CSS inspector" means exactly that, that the property was _overwritten_ from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling.css file is above the bootstrap css file, which results in your style being overridden by bootstrap. Bring that down below the bootstrap css file for your styles to apply.